# 1 Action ability that triggers Conduct Energy

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

I am looking for a 1 action activity with the acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic trait to trigger [Conduct Energy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=704). As I want to attack with a weapon after it, this action should not increase MAP.

So far I only found 3:

- Witch Hex cantrip: [Clinging Ice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1887)
- Witch Focus spell: [Personal Blizzard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1883)
- Oracle Focus spell: [Temptest Touch](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=763)

These are not great if I want to use a weapon, I would prefer something that can be used by any class, preferably on level 5 the latest. Also, it should be usable every round, at most by spending a Focus Point.

Comment: The question is not _about_ a magic item itself, but triggering that magic item. If you have a better tag, just replace it.

Comment: I think the tag is fine. I changed the title a bit because I came here wondering why you were wanting to spend an action on Conduct Energy. I think the slight changes make it pretty clear you're looking for Action(s) that can allow you to use CE after them

Comment: This should be a 2e.aonprd link that works for this question: https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?include-actions=Free%20Action+Single%20Action+Single%20Action%20or%20Two%20Actions+Single%20Action%20to%20Three%20Actions+Single%20Action%20to%20Two%20Actions&include-traits=acid+cold+electricity+fire+sonic&exclude-traits=metamagic+spellshape&traits-operator=or&include-types=action+feat+spell&exclude-types=item&display=short - I'll summarize my best findings in a quick answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Few Good Options

I'm using this [AoN query](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?include-actions=Free%20Action+Single%20Action+Single%20Action%20or%20Two%20Actions+Single%20Action%20to%20Three%20Actions+Single%20Action%20to%20Two%20Actions&include-traits=acid+cold+electricity+fire+sonic&exclude-traits=metamagic+spellshape&traits-operator=or&include-types=action+feat+spell&exclude-types=item&display=short) - it searches for abilities that can be used as a free action or with one action that have one of the requisite traits and are NOT items nor metamagic/spellshape abilities. You could further the list more (such as negating all the class traits), but there's only 26 options at this time so I just manually skimmed them.

The easiest to access option is probably the [Illuminate cantrip](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1359). Any spellcasting multiclass archetype and all spellcasters should have access to that. Admittedly, it's almost useless in combat. You might be interested in Magus's [Thunderous Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1044) (which is a focus spell) or Inventor's [Explosive Leap](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3045) (which is Unstable and so might be tough to use more than once a combat). Multiclassing into an Elemental Sorcerer for [Elemental Toss](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=505) is another option (1 action focus spell). Rage for a [Dragon Instinct Barbarian](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=2) would work, and it's arguably an oversight that [Elemental Barbarian's Rage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=7) doesn't (ask your GM). If you can grab Elemental Barbarian, then a Kineticist multiclass would be helpful to give you a variety of viable actions - your basic [Elemental Blast](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=2125) would even trigger it (though I imagine your build wants to avoid MAP generating actions).

Comment: I do not think you can get Hex cantrips from a Witch archetype

Comment: @András good point, I'll remove that suggestion. I'd assumed you could without checking.