# How can I search for 1 action activities?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, tools

I tried searching on Archives of Nethys to find the answer for [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/211048/1-action-activity-to-trigger-conduct-energy), but I just do not know how.
In Complex Search, I should be able to filter for actions, in the help it says:

> **actions** Actions or time required to use an action or activity

I tried "actions:1", "actions:one-action" and "actions:one", but there are 0 results, which is obviously wrong.

Am I doing something wrong, or have I found a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the complex search, the syntax to search for single action activities is:

```
actions.keyword:"Single Action"
```

With the standard search, there is an option for single action under the Actions/Cast Time filter category.